# How can I include private pages in a page list?

Tags: wp-list-pages

I'm currently using wp_list_pages to show site pages.

It doesn't include private pages, so I need to find a way to produce a list of them too.

I can do it with a plugin, but it includes various options I don't need and I prefer to hardcode something appropriate into a template.

Comment: Not enough information provided, add your code that your using.

Comment: @Malisa... Thanks. I hadn't seen your reply when I answered the post below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add a `post_status` argument:

```
wp_list_pages( array(
    'post_status' => array( 'publish', 'private' ),
));
```

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been tracking since eight years ago, and it's not fixed yet (see  https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/8592)

Maybe you should replace `wp_list_pages()` with `get_pages()` and some php to generate your list due `get_pages()` allows you to find private pages too (see https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages)

Comment: Thanks. I'd tried the default example from that codex page, and was getting no info displayed.

Comment: And that's a normal behavior: `array get_pages($args)`, it returns an Array of _posts_ objects. You should iterate it with some foreach bucle and extract desired fields to compose your html

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Currently though, that's beyond my knowledge - but I'll add it to my list of things to learn.